# how to pass the result of custom query in pagination

Tags: php, cakephp-1.3

hi i am using cakephp for my project but i am fetching  problem when i generate result from custom query at that time i have no idea about that how to pass that result in to pagination.
so please help me.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the book (http://book.cakephp.org/view/249/Custom-Query-Pagination)

Bascially, you would override paginate in the model you want to get the data from. If it will mess up the model, just create a new custom model that uses the same table and put the paginate override in there.